# Element UI date Picker CSS design doesn't change in Vue CLI project

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I would like to change some styeles of Element UI date picker.
for example, the popup is too far to the left, so I would like to move right a little.

I reference the original site and tried to adapt the code, however the style doesn't change.
https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/date-picker.html#attributes

[image]

My code like this:

```
<template>

<el-date-picker v-model="value2" type="daterange" unlink-panels range-separator="〜"
start-placeholder="Start date" end-placeholder="End date" :shortcuts="shortcuts"
popper-class="my-popover" />

</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  ::deep(.my-popover) {
    padding: 1000px 30px;
    background-color: #03cfb4;
    left:  1000px !important;
  }
</style>
```

Are there any misunderstandings of my code and the solutions?
Thank you in advance!

my-popover is added like this:
[image]

Comment: Try without `scoped`.

Comment: Thnak you. I tried it but the problem of the style not being applied has not been resolved. (my-popover class itself is correctly added.)

Comment: You should try to find the popover inside the Elements tab in DevTools and see what CSS selectors are matching it. If your CSS class `.my-popover` is not there - it means it is not matching and you will have to tweak the selector a bit until it matches.

Comment: I solved thanks to your advice!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I specified the following and it worked!

```
<template>

<el-date-picker v-model="value2" type="daterange" unlink-panels range-separator="〜"
start-placeholder="Start date" end-placeholder="End date" :shortcuts="shortcuts"
popper-class="my-popover" />

</template>

<style lang="scss">
.my-popover {
  left: 250px !important;
}
</style>
```